# Ember not returing a DSRecordArray on find(model,id)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using a REST adapter and serializer to pull in data from `this.store.find(modelName, id)`

In my serializer, I am successfully attaining an array from my REST api and extracting it into the store.

Why does does Ember think that if you gave it an ID in the `find()` parameters, that it must be a singular object?

Giving it query parameters returns collections of records however my REST API does not support that. Is there a way to set the result returned to become a record array? --- while not losing ember data cache functionality?

I would like the record array to be cached with the key `id` i've given in the `find()`

Comment: ember-data thinks that it must be a singular item, because you can't have more items with the same id. could it be that you want something like `this.store.find(modelName, { bar: "foo"})` ?

Comment: data persistence !== data caching

Comment: @Jeff Yes that would be ideal to return a record array to model but I cannot grab the id from my REST adapter in order to build the URl to  `www.domain.com/route/:id` it always creates `www.domain.com/route?id=:id`.

Comment: @Kitler So here I'm referring to caching records as in avoid round trips to the database (persistent) collection and I want to know if thats possible using `ember-data` when giving it an `id` param